# What difficulty do you have to be on in Minecraft survival to find sheep?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been looking for sheep for almost 2 Minecraft days; I need to find them to get wool and make a bed. I can't find any spiders either to get string to spin into wool.

I'm currently on Easy difficulty. What difficulty must I be on to find sheep?

Comment: Sheep only appear in certain biomes, but their spawning isn't affected by difficulty.  If you have other animals and hostile mobs spawning, then sheep will spawn too.

Answer (score 6):

Sheep spawn on any difficulty, and on any setting. They do however require at least 2 blocks of grass, not dirt, in a 10x10 area of grass, and sunlight. They will only spawn during daytime. By default, every 80 seconds the server will throw a dice to see if, and how many creatures will spawn. This can be sheep, pigs, chickens or anything like it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a difficulty to find sheep. They naturally spawn and can be found anywhere. If you are having trouble finding sheep you could use a spawn egg or look in plains biomes. If you are specifically looking for wool to make a bed craft wool out of string.